# Using the awesome angularAudioRecorder but can't seem to work with the audio-model blob in my controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been using the following awesome plugin 'angularAudioRecorder' to build a simple voice recorder app in AngularJS/Ionic.  Been messing with CordovaMedia and ngCordova media plugins for days, then this dropped in and worked a treat.

My issue now is that I can't seem to reference to the recorded blob in my apps controller.

See below for the snippet of the html which works a charm.

```
<ng-audio-recorder id='audioInput' audio-model='recordedInput' time-limit='2' on-record-complete="finished()">

  <!-- Start controls, exposed via recorder-->
    <div ng-if="recorder.isAvailable">
      <a ng-click="recorder.status.isRecording ? recorder.stopRecord() : recorder.startRecord()" id="recordBarK-button10" style="color:#F5AA2C;" class="button button-light button-large button-block button-outline" ng-class="{'btn-primary': !recorder.status.isRecording, 'btn-danger': recorder.status.isRecording}">{{recorder.status.isRecording ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}} Recording</a>
    </div>
</ng-audio-recorder>
```

And here is my controller for the template:

```
.controller('recordBarKCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading) {

$scope.finished = function() {
    alert("im done recording now");
    alert($scope.audioInput.size);
    //$state.go('previewBarK');
}
```

})

The finished function gets called fine, but the issue is I can't seem to reference the audio recording, which is I believe supposed to be available vie the 'audio-model' I defined as recordedInput.  I am probably getting something very basic wrong here but I hope someone help me out of the dark.

plugin docs are here: http://logbon72.github.io/angular-recorder/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check out the demo. But it didn't work.

And I found this:

> As per new chrome update (From Google Chrome 47), getUserMedia() is no longer supported in chrome browser over http:// (Unsecure Origin) , It will work on https:// (Secure Origin)

It means you need https to be able to make this thing working. There are a number of WebRTC solutions. But I guess now, they also need HTTPS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pass the recorder object to your function  like following :

```
<ng-audio-recorder id='audioInput_<% audio_to_client_id %>' audio-model='recordedInput'
                   on-conversion-complete="finished(recorder)"
                   on-record-start="clearPrevRecord()">
```

and in your controller  do the following :

```
$scope.audio_blob = null
$scope.record_object = null
$scope.finished = function(record) {
    $scope.audio_blob = record.audioModel
    $scope.record_object = record
}
```

then you are able to get the blob object the record object in your controller.